# MongoDB $in on specific fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I have data in the form

```
{
field1 : a,
field2 : b,
field3 : c
},
{
field1 : d,
field2 : e,
field3 : f
},
...
```

I also have an array of objects like

```
[
{
field1 : a,
field2 : b,
},
{
field1 : d
field2 : h
}
]
```

What I want is all elements in my database where the elements match the documents in the array, but only on the fields in the array. That is, I want an $in that would be, in words "Where the tuple made by field1 and field2 is in the array". So here, I would get back the first element in my database, but not the second.

Is there any way to do this? A Java answer is preferred, but I should be able to work off of a general mongo answer.

Thank you!

Comment: You can try $or. Something like this `db.collection.find({
    $or: [
         {field1: 'a', field2: 'b'},
         {field1 : 'd', field2 : 'h'}
    ]
});`

Comment: That would probably work, but I have like 20 of these guys. Might be the best I can do though.